# mongodb part of the array

Tags: mongodb

I have a schema which looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f6af5c7065f92581a000013"),
  ....
  "conversation" : [{
      "_id" : ObjectId("4f6af5c7065f92581a000013"),
      "msg" : "message1",
      "userID" : 1
    },{
      "_id" : ObjectId("4f6af5c7065f92581a000016"),
      "msg" : "message3",
      "userID" : 1
    },{
      "_id" : ObjectId("4f6af5c7065f92581a000023"),
      "msg" : "msg",
      "userID" : 1
    }]
}
```

What I need is to output a list of elements whose value for the key msg contains 'msg'
Is it possible to do so?

```
db.dialogs.find({ "_id" : new ObjectId('4f6af5c7065f92581a000013'), "conversation.msg" : /msg/i })
```

but it outputs all the information about the object. What I need is just

```
{
          "_id" : ObjectId("4f6af5c7065f92581a000023"),
          "msg" : "msg",
          "userID" : 1
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't select elements of sub-array on their own. Structure of parent document will be preserved (though, you may choose not to select from fields other tnan conversation (as you did in the example)).